# How to fill rectangle (c++, mfc)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, 2d, draw

I need to fill the part of "Rectangle"(diagonall filling)[image](like on this image).
How to do it on mfc ? Sorry for my bad english!

```
void CKonokhovView::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
if (m_Dragging){
    m_Dragging = 0;
    ::ReleaseCapture();
    ::ClipCursor(NULL);
    CKonokhovDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    CClientDC ClientDC(this);
    CPen pen;
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, pDoc->docColor);
    ClientDC.SelectObject(&pen);
    ClientDC.SetROP2(R2_NOT);
    ClientDC.Rectangle(m_PointOrigin.x, m_PointOrigin.y, m_PointOld.x,      m_PointOld.y);
    ClientDC.SetROP2(R2_COPYPEN);
    CBrush* oldBrush = ClientDC.SelectObject(&nullBrush);
    ClientDC.Rectangle(m_PointOrigin.x, m_PointOrigin.y, point.x, point.y);

    pDoc->AddLine(m_PointOrigin.x, m_PointOrigin.y, point.x, point.y);
    ClientDC.SelectObject(&oldBrush);


}
```

Comment: You could use region objects

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CDC::Polygon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhkhd4xz.aspx), which is a wrapper for [Polygon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162814(v=vs.85).aspx) API

Example:

```
CRect rc(0, 0, 100, 100);
CPoint points[3];
points[0] = CPoint(rc.left, rc.top);
points[1] = CPoint(rc.right, rc.top);
points[2] = CPoint(rc.left, rc.bottom);

ClientDC.Polygon(points, 3);
```